# Alternative to Bukkit's world-edit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

I play on a minecraft server. The admin likes a plugin that uses /sp. I aksed him to install world edit, so he did. He then uninstalled it when he realised that it overwrote /sp. So I'm looking for a good alternative to world-edit.

Comment: Can't you change World Edit so it doesn't use `/sp`? :)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of an /sp command in WorldEdit.  At any rate, @badp is correct, you can manually change the command syntax of most plugins.

Comment: @badp yes, since the [source code](https://github.com/sk89q/worldedit) is available that should be possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, `/sp` is just an alias for `/superpickaxe`. You could easily change this to anything else. Just open the WorldEdit.jar with any ZIP unarchiver and edit the plugin.yml file that's inside. It's a large file, so just do a Ctrl-F and search for 'superpickaxe' to find what you're looking for. It should look like this:

```
superpickaxe:
    description: Select super pickaxe mode
    usage: /<command> 
    aliases: ['pickaxe', 'sp']
```

See the line that says `aliases: ['pickaxe', 'sp']`? Just remove the 'sp' and replace it with whatever you want. That should fix the issues. Then just rearchive the JAR and run the server.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is this plugin

[Essentials](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/gen-sec-econ-tp-admn-essentials-v2-5-7-a-collection-of-useful-commands-and-features-1060.15312/)

They have some commands to edit the world but it's not as good as World Edit and nothing will replace that. So after some search: no, there's no alternative for WorldEdit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called **buildr** which is not quite as complex as worldedit, but quite easy to use. However it overwrites the /give command, slightly modifying the syntax which may not be desireable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [source code](https://github.com/sk89q/worldedit) of WorldEdit is available, you *could* modify that command and recompile it by yourself, or hope your admin would do this for you.